# I keep getting this error in Django, its called "local variable referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, django

I am making this to-do list website with Django, but I keep getting this error in my "create" function in views.py file. here's the code :

```
def create(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = CreateNewList(response.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            n = form.cleaned_data["name"]
            t = ToDoList(name=n)
            t.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect("/%i" %t.id)
```

here's the error :

```
local variable 't' referenced before assignment
```

the class of the form is :

```
from django import forms


class CreateNewList(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="name", max_length=200)
    check = forms.BooleanField()
```

the models are :

```
from django.db import models


class ToDoList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Item(models.Model):
    todolist = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    complete = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

I tried assigning the variable before the if statement. here's the code :

```
def create(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = CreateNewList(response.POST)
        t = ToDoList.objects
        if form.is_valid():
            n = form.cleaned_data["name"]
            t.create(name=n)
            t.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect("/%i" %t.id)

    else:
        form = CreateNewList()

    return render(response, "main/create.html", {"form":form})
```

Comment: what if form is not valid

Comment: what do you mean by if the form is valid or not?

Comment: what if ->    if form.is_valid(): returns false how do you expect t variable to be set in this  line          return HttpResponseRedirect("/%i" %t.id)

Comment: yeah, what is form.is_valid()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create `t` object, you need to do it like:

```
...
t = ToDoList.objects.create(name=n)
t.save()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61649424/django-local-variable-t-referenced-before-assignment, check this out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `t` is defined in the `if` clause which might not always get satisfied and you end up with the error: `local variable 't' referenced before assignment`.

The fix could be to either create the `t` object before the `if` block with some default setting (None) or indent the `return` statement if that's what you wanted.